# Sorting Movies By 2 Things

Tags: php, mysql

Hay everyone need abit of help i a noob when it come to php :(

In my database i have a table called movies and i have 12 columns in there but i used 2 collumns for sorting my movies and there are called year and the other 1 is imdb_rating

this is how i sort them

```
 public function getRealMovies($lang=null, $p=null, $l=null, $sortby=null){
    $movies = array();

    if (($p) && ($l)){
        $start = ($p-1)*$l;
        $limit = " LIMIT $start,$l";
    } else {
        $limit = '';
    }

    if (!$sortby || $sortby=='abc'){
        $order = "ORDER BY title ASC";
    } elseif ($sortby=='date'){
        $order = "ORDER BY date_added DESC";
    } elseif ($sortby=='imdb_rating'){
        $order = "ORDER BY imdb_rating DESC";
    } elseif ($sortby=='year'){
        $order = "ORDER BY year DESC";
    }

    $e = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE id IN (SELECT movie_id FROM movie_embeds) $order $limit") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($e)>0){

        $ids = array();

        while($s = mysql_fetch_array($e)){
            $movies[$s['id']] = $this->formatMovieData($s, $lang);
            $ids[] = $s['id'];
        }

        if (count($ids)){

            $flags = $this->getFlags($ids);

            if (count($flags)){
                foreach($movies as $movie_id => $val){
                    if (array_key_exists($movie_id,$flags)){
                        $movies[$movie_id]['languages'] = $flags[$movie_id];
                    } else {
                        $movies[$movie_id]['languages'] = array();
                    }    
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return $movies;
}
```

Would it be possible to sort by 2 things for example

```
     } elseif ($sortby=='imdb_rating and year'){
        $order = "ORDER BY imdb_rating and year DESC";
```

i hope some one can help

thanks

Comment: It didn't work it sorts only by imdb_rating not by year any other ideas

Answer (score 2):

Just separate the columns with commas:

```
elseif($sortby == 'imdb_rating and year')
{
    $order = 'ORDER BY `imbd_rating`, `year` DESC';
}
```

Alternatively, if you'd like to order them differently (for example by year and then rating), use:

```
ORDER BY `year` DESC, `imdb_rating` ASC
```

It's also worth noting that the `mysql_*` set of function is now deprecated. It'd be better to use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1):

Just seperate the order columns by a comma.

```
$order = "ORDER BY imdb_rating, year DESC";
```

You should definitely consider to use another MySQL extension as well, `mysql_*` is deprecated, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. I prefer PDO.

Comment: I think the imdb_rating will be sorted `ASC` if you do not define `DESC`.

Comment: what would the rewrite rule by for that then example RewriteRule ^/?tv-shows/imdb_rating index.php?menu=tv-shows&sortby=imdb_rating&lang=en [L]

Comment: @TobiasKun That's right, I wasn't sure if he wanted both the columns sorted DESC, but just add DESC to imdb_rating as well if that's what you want.

Comment: No what i mean is how would i add year as well in to the rewrite rule :)

Comment: @AshWill Don't ask additional questions in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the syntax slightly.

```
"ORDER BY imdb_rating DESC, year DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `and` with a simple comma:

```
ORDER BY imdb_rating DESC, year DESC
```