# Movies Won't Sortby

Tags: php, mysql

Hay everyone help a bit of help.

On my movies page i can sort movies by 4 things but only 1 at a time

```
    ABC
Date Added
Imdb Ratings
Year
```

But i tried to do is sort the movies by 2 things at once Year and Imdb Ratings but it wont work.

Could you please check what is causing the error

here is the  public function code

```
 public function getRealMovies($lang=null, $p=null, $l=null, $sortby=null){
    $movies = array();

    if (($p) && ($l)){
        $start = ($p-1)*$l;
        $limit = " LIMIT $start,$l";
    } else {
        $limit = '';
    }

    if (!$sortby || $sortby=='abc'){
        $order = "ORDER BY title ASC";
    } elseif ($sortby=='date'){
        $order = "ORDER BY date_added DESC";
    } elseif ($sortby=='imdb_rating'){
        $order = "ORDER BY imdb_rating DESC";
    } elseif ($sortby=='year'){
        $order = "ORDER BY year DESC";
    } elseif ($sortby=='imdb_rating&year'){
        $order = "ORDER BY imdb_rating, year DESC";        
    }

    $e = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE id IN (SELECT movie_id FROM movie_embeds) $order $limit") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($e)>0){

        $ids = array();

        while($s = mysql_fetch_array($e)){
            $movies[$s['id']] = $this->formatMovieData($s, $lang);
            $ids[] = $s['id'];
        }

        if (count($ids)){

            $flags = $this->getFlags($ids);

            if (count($flags)){
                foreach($movies as $movie_id => $val){
                    if (array_key_exists($movie_id,$flags)){
                        $movies[$movie_id]['languages'] = $flags[$movie_id];
                    } else {
                        $movies[$movie_id]['languages'] = array();
                    }    
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return $movies;
}
```

And here is the Rewrite Roles

```
RewriteRule ^/?movies/(\d+)$ index.php?menu=movies&p=$1&sortby=abc&lang=en [L]
RewriteRule ^/?movies/abc/(\d+)$ index.php?menu=movies&p=$1&sortby=abc&lang=en [L]
RewriteRule ^/?movies/date/(\d+)$ index.php?menu=movies&p=$1&sortby=date&lang=en [L]
RewriteRule ^/?movies/imdb_rating/(\d+)$ index.php?menu=movies&p=$1&sortby=imdb_rating&lang=en
RewriteRule ^/?movies/year/(\d+)$ index.php?menu=movies&p=$1&sortby=year&lang=en
RewriteRule ^/?movies/date index.php?menu=movies&sortby=date&lang=en
RewriteRule ^/?movies/abc index.php?menu=movies&sortby=abc&lang=en
RewriteRule ^/?movies/imdb_rating index.php?menu=movies&sortby=imdb_rating&lang=en
RewriteRule ^/?movies/year index.php?menu=movies&sortby=year&lang=en
RewriteRule ^/?movies/fav index.php?menu=movies&sortby=imdb_rating&year&lang=en
RewriteRule ^/?movies index.php?menu=movies&lang=en [L]
RewriteRule ^/?requests index.php?menu=requests&lang=en [L]
```

And here are the bottons

```
                    <li{if $sortby eq 'abc'} class="current"{/if}><a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.movies}/abc">{$lang.sorting_abc}</a></li>
                <li{if $sortby eq 'date'} class="current"{/if}><a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.movies}/date">{$lang.sorting_newest}</a></li>
                <li{if $sortby eq 'imdb_rating'} class="current"{/if}><a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.movies}/imdb_rating">{$lang.sorting_imdb}</a></li>
                <li{if $sortby eq 'year'} class="current"{/if}><a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.movies}/year">{$lang.released}</a></li>
                <li{if $sortby eq 'imdb_rating&year'} class="current"{/if}><a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.movies}/imdb_rating&year">Fav</a></li>
            {else}
                <li{if $sortby eq 'abc'} class="current"{/if}><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=movies&sortby=abc">{$lang.sorting_abc}</a></li>
                <li{if $sortby eq 'date'} class="current"{/if}><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=movies&sortby=date">{$lang.sorting_newest}</a></li>
                <li{if $sortby eq 'imdb_rating'} class="current"{/if}><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=movies&sortby=imdb_rating">{$lang.sorting_imdb}</a></li>
                <li{if $sortby eq 'year'} class="current"{/if}><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=movies&sortby=year">{$lang.released}</a></li>
                <li{if $sortby eq 'imdb_rating&year'} class="current"{/if}><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=movies&sortby=imdb_rating&year">Fav</a></li>
```

Can any one help please

thanks :)

Comment: You should update your old [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920068/sorting-movies-by-2-things).

Comment: Switch case really exists

Comment: RewriteRule is a rewrite ROLE, and a button is botton, I just had to comment that I laughed :) it's not even a simple spelling mistake, it's RENAMING. There are some unique people on this world for sure :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using condition `elseif ($sortby=='imdb_rating&year')` but `&year` is a new key in the GET HTTP request, in other words `$sortby` has only the `'imdb_rating'` value in this case.

You must use another separator, for example:

```
elseif ($sortby=='imdb_rating_and_year')
```

And change rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/?movies/fav index.php?menu=movies&sortby=imdb_rating&year&lang=en
```

to this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?movies/fav index.php?menu=movies&sortby=imdb_rating_and_year&lang=en
```

and same changes in the template.